# Pointer to Vector of Objects in another Class c++

Tags: c++, class, pointers, vector

I have prepared a simplified code example of what I am trying to do. Basically I have 3 classes A B C. Class B reads in data an stores it in a vector where each entry is an object of class A. Inside class B I can now work with the stored data perfectly fine, but I want to be able to pass the data on to a 3rd class (or more classes) with a reference like.

B b(...);

C (&b);

for the members of B this works, but if I try to create a pointer to the stored vector it fails. The important one here is the vector "v", the vector "w" only exists because I wanted to see what happens with an int-vector (there I can at least access its content with ->at(..), but returning via "int gg(int l) {return w.at(l);}" still fails).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class A
{
    string fname;
    int id;
public:
    A(const string a, int ID):fname(a),id(ID) {}
    string rfname() {return fname;}

};

class B
{
    vector<A> v;
    vector<int> w;
public:
    B(const string a, int ID);
    vector<A> *rv() {return &v;}
    vector<int> *rw() {return &w;}
    int gg(int l) {return w.at(l);}
    void ggg(){cout << "test test" << endl;}
};

B::B(const string a, int ID)
{
    v.push_back(A(a,ID));
    w.push_back(ID);
    //cout << "test: " << gg(0) << endl;
}

class C
{
    B *BB;
    vector<int> *u;
    vector<A> *aa;
public:
    C(B *U);
};

C::C (B *U)
{
    BB = U;
    BB->ggg();
    aa = BB->rv();
    u = BB->rw();
    cout << "sdfdsfdsf: " << u->at(0) << endl;
    cout << "kkkkkk: " << aa->rfname() << endl; //this fails
}

int main()
{

    B b("test",24);
    vector<int> *ww;
    ww = b.rw();
    vector<A> *vv;
    vv = b.rv();
    //cout << ww->gg(0) << endl; //this fails
    cout << ww->at(0) << endl;
    //cout << vv[0]->rfname() << endl; //this fails
    C c(&b);

}
```

basically I get errors like

```
'class std::vector<A, std::allocator<A> >' has no member named 'rfname'|
```

when I try aa->rfname() and so on.

I should note that I only got back into programming a few weeks back because I have to analyze some data and therefore I am not very experienced in coding. So I am probably missing something very basic and would be thankfull for rather simple solutions. Already searched for similar topics, but I still wasn't able to get it to work.

Comment: This code is wrong in so many ways and spiced with serious misconceptions, that it's simply going too broad to fix all of this properly here. But for starters: Why on earth you are using a `std::vector<A>*` pointer instead of a simple member `std::vector<A> aa`?

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear. If you were asking a question, that would most likely be the answer to it.

Comment: As for my first comment: In class `C` `std::vector<A>* aa;` should be a `std::vector<A>& aa;` whatever this will be good for.

Answer (score 1):

This is the culprit:

```
cout << "kkkkkk: " << aa->rfname() << endl; //this fails
```

`aa` is a `std::vector<A>*`. `->` accesses a member of the vector. `rfname` is not a member function of `std::vector`.

But what is the supposed meaning of this line of code, anyway? Are you attempting to print the entire contents of the vector? Then you have to iterate over the vector and print each element:

```
for (std::vector<A>::iterator iter = aa->begin(); iter != aa->end(); ++iter)
{
  cout << "kkkkkk: " << iter->rfname() << endl;
}
```

The code is still wrong in too many ways to explain every problem individually. For starters, `rfname` should be a const member function, and you should probably not use any pointers at all. And I seriously hope that all your classes, variables and functions are not really named liked this.

Comment: Expect a lot of callbacks from the OP now. But anyway +1, good explanation what happens in 1st place, and how to fix it.

Comment: Its just a simpled down code to whats actually happening. Whats actually happening is that Class B reads in a lot of data which gets stored in 2 vectors (1 contains file infos like date, the other actuall data from the files). The purpose now is to do various calculations with the data and give it out, which is irrelevant to post here.
What I only want is to somehow pass on a pointer to the data so that I can pass the already complete read-in information to different classes, so that I don't have to write every algorythm as a member of class B.

Comment: @MilesTeg If this is already _simpled down_, you should better have invested your time into writing a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).